# Delete... Left Join query in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am developing an iOS and Android application using Xamarin Forms. I have the following code:

```
db2.Execute("DELETE w FROM Word AS w" +
            " LEFT JOIN WordSource AS ws ON ws.WordId = w.WordId" +
            " WHERE ws.WordId IS NULL");
```

But I kept getting syntax error near w. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? Is `DELETE... JOIN...` query not supported in sqlite? If so, how can I accomplished this code in sqlite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way is based on an a in clause and subselect with left join

```
db2.Execute( "DELETE  FROM Word WHERE id in (  
                SELECT id FROM Word as W  
                LEFT JOIN WordSource AS ws ON ws.WordId = w.WordId 
                WHERE ws.WordId IS NULL
              )");
```